# The review page

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there was any review page where you could see which reviews were correct (or dis / agreed with it?) I know you can see all the reviews you have done, but not any right/ wrong stats.

Comment: If we could make a page showing which reviews were correct, we wouldn't need review. For (dis-)agreement, there's a dupe.

Comment: @Deduplicator I was kind of thinking that, but was thinking it may show what all other reviewers thought of it, but yeah, it would be kind of pointless, I was just wondering.